# Proper electrical cable disconnect procedure for purge valve?

Tags: electrical, exhaust, valve

Attempting to replace a canister purge valve (pictured)

[image]

Some of the instructions I've read say to disconnect the battery terminals prior to remove the electrical cable and removing the valve.

That seems like overkill. Could I not just unplug the electrical connection from the valve without worrying about the battery at all?

[image]

Or - does the risk in leaving the battery connected occur when reconnecting the electrical to the new valve?

I'm just getting my feet wet in DIY repairs and this seems like an easy enough fix. I hate messing with battery terminals so if I can reasonably, safely get away with not touching them (figuratively and literally) I'd be much happier!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the ignition has been turned off for more that a few minutes (i.e the key has been out of the ignition for 5 minutes) you will be fine to disconnect it and reconnect the new one.

The problem arises if you turn the ignition on when it is disconnected as the ECU may log a fault code a throw a check engine light.

So as long as the ignition is off and you unplug the old one and reconnect the new one without turning the ignition on you will be fine.

Comment: Considering I'm trying to resolve a check engine light, I'd hate to create more reasons for the light to fire!

Comment: If the check engine light is already on is there's nothing to worry about then. You'll never do any physical damage, the worst that can happen is the check engine light comes on